# Laravel 8 Seeder Results in +22 vendor frames 24 artisan:37 Error and Doesn't Seed

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to seed my database but it stops and shows the following error in the console. As with all my seed files, I run `php artisan seed:db --class=GeneratorSeeder`

```
+22 vendor frames 24  artisan:37
    Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)).
```

I've inserted an image below to show the error.  I have several seed files exactly like this and they work perfectly consistent every time.  This particular seed file is 2961 records and over 20k fields, but that shouldn't be the issue.  I've double checked that all my field names and my json data file for errors.

**GeneratorSeeder.php**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;
use App\Models\Generator;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class GeneratorSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $json = file_get_contents('database/data/eli-generators.json');
        $data = json_decode($json);

        foreach ($data as $obj) {
            Generator::create(array(
                'generator_name' => $obj->generator_name,
                'generator_street_address_one' => $obj->generator_street_address_one,
                'generator_city' => $obj->generator_city,
                'generator_state' => $obj->generator_state,
                'generator_postal_code' => $obj->generator_postal_code
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: is your json file contain big data or has small information?

Comment: I think the longest field is probably 120 characters and is a `string` type in my migration table.

Answer (score 0):

if there is an issue of execution time than put your json data in collection and make chunk of your data to insert in table

```
$collect = collect($data);
foreach($collect->chunk(100) as $chunk){
  Generator::insert($chunk->toArray());
}
```

create take some to insert data in database. with insert you can add bulk data. hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I entered it as is and as `[ 'generator_name' => $chunk->generator_name, ... ]` and the seed completes immediately but doesn't seed.

Answer (score 0):

While pulling my hair out, I decided to create a new json data file and paste my formatted code into it and it seeded properly.  The only thing I can think of--I started with an Excel file then used an online tool to convert the Excel file to json.  When I downloaded the converted file, it downloaded as a txt file. I simply renamed it and added it to my project.  Although it was valid json markup, something about the txt renamed with json extension caused the issue. I hope this saves someone some time in the future.